# stripe.confirmPayment() create new payment intent every second - cash app integration

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to add the cash_app payment method to my website according to Stripe docs:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cash-app-pay/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements

when im start the payment process:

```
const {error} = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    //`Elements` instance that was used to create the Payment Element
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
      return_url: 'https://example.com/order/123/complete',
    },
  });
```

im check the browser network and see there is new payment intent every second

[image]

this leads to 2 problems:

1. my stripe payments records are dirty with uncomplete payments
2. some of the payments decline because of fraud behavior

how can I avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need a secret API key to create a PaymentIntent, which usually happens in your backend where the secret API key resides.

The console log doesn't show the complete PaymentIntent IDs, but these IDs all look the same to me. My guess is that this page is just sending GET requests with the same PaymentIntent ID to query the PaymentIntent status, not POST requests to create new PaymentIntents.